# Class from database

Tags: c#, database

I'm trying to create report from **DevExpress**; however, I'm having a problem when I try to declare a class and naming it from of a table in the database, similarly to the example below:

```
Database
ID(int), Class_Name(string)
```

Class `Report` would have a similar functions to these:

```
getReport();
setReport();
```

Using normal syntax, it would be:

```
Report rpt = new Report();
rpt.getReport();
rpt.setReport();
//etc....
```

However, class `Report` is the same as `Class_Name` in the database.  If I use the normal syntax with the database, I believe it would look like this:

```
row[i].getString().substring(-2) data = new  row[i].getString()+"()";
data.getReport();
data.setReport();
```

However, I do not have any success with the above.

Comment: That's usually a bad idea.  You may want to learn about Reflection.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do. "trying to create report from DevExpress" - does that mean creating a report using the DevExpress Reports facility?

Comment: And when you talk about a "database" do you mean an existing database that contains the data you want to show in the report? If so, there should be some interface routines available for reading the database into a C# program as some kind of object collection. For example, if the database supports an ODBC interface then C# has classes like OdbcConnection, OdbcCommand and OdbcDataReader. Once you have the data in a C# data collection it should be fairly easy to get the DevExpress Reports facility to produce an attractive report for the data.

Comment: yes i create report using devExpress, and with database its mean, when i create report with it, the code will became a class with name Report(for Example) and i save in database with ID and Class_Name (Report) so, have you all any idea i get string from table with row (Class_Name) can be declare in code like sample i create before.....